# How to implement Apple Pay with Stripe in Xamarin forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe in Xamarin forms with Apply Pay

I am following the following [tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) but I am stuck at one problem I can't find the `STPApplePayContext` class in Xamarin

The Library I am using

[IOS Bindings](https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) or  [Xamarin.Stripe.iOS](https://github.com/NAXAM/stripe-ios-binding)

Both provide iOS binidngs for Stripe.

Now as I am following the tutorial I can't find the `STPApplePayContext` in any of those Libs or something similar.

My code with iOS Bindings

```
        public Task<bool> InitializeAsync(string clientToken)
        {
            // STPPaymentConfiguration
            StripeSdk.STPPaymentConfiguration.SharedConfiguration().PublishableKey =
                "pk_test_123456";
            _canPay = Stripe_ApplePay.DeviceSupportsApplePay;
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public bool CreatePaymentRequest(double amount)
        {
            _paymentRequest = _stripe.PaymentRequestWithMerchantIdentifier(_merchantID,"US","USD");
            _paymentRequest.SupportedNetworks = _paymentNetworks;
            _paymentRequest.MerchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.ThreeDS;

            _paymentRequest.PaymentSummaryItems = new[]
            {
                new PKPaymentSummaryItem()
                {
                    Label = "Item",
                    Amount = new NSDecimalNumber(amount)
                }
            };
            return true;
        }

        public bool Pay()
        {
         
            // var applePayContext = STPApplePayContext;
            // if (applePayContext)
            // {
            // }
            // if let applePayContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentRequest, delegate: self) {
            //     // Present Apple Pay payment sheet
            //     applePayContext.presentApplePay(on: self)
            // } else {
            //     // There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration
            // }
        }
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: STPApplePayContext is [quite new](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1910-2020-04-15), you're probably using an older version of the stripe-ios library that doesn't have it.

Comment: Is there any iOS binding for something new or recent?

Comment: I'm not sure. Looks like that Xamarin library is using version of stripe-ios that's 6 versions behind, maybe ask the maintainers if they can update it? Also, the current docs only use the STPApplePayContext, but you can look at [older docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20191003151330/https://stripe.com/docs/apple-pay) and see how to integrate without it, by implementing  PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate instead.

Comment: Older docs means old vulnerabilities. meaning risk

Comment: Hmm, ok, I was mainly just linking them to demonstrate how to implement Apple Pay using the older version of the library that you have in the hopes it would help. As I mentioned, you can switch to the newer version of the library(but that's complicated since you don't own the Xamarin binding), or integrate directly with a PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController which will definitely work and has docs(just Stripe doesn't publish docs for older version of their libraries.)

Comment: I was able to do it with PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController it was quite easy just two three lines of code. Sadly the documentation was not quite helpful

Comment: @supernerd Can you share your PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController sample?

Comment: @user246392 I left the company during covid, so don't have the code.